# How do test for a certain user input and throw away all the other inputs?

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering how do i test for a number the the user inputs and send them somewhere with goto but if its any other number it will send them there. so i was thinking about using if but for some reason its not working. any tips? I am also very new to batch so if i make some rookie mistakes. (edit) im sorry if i wasn't clear. what i want it to do is when the user inputs the number 6 i want it too take him to h but if any other input (numbers, letters, ect) is entered i want it to take them to n

```
@ECHO OFF
set /p number=
SET /a number=6
if %number% NEQ 6 goto n
if %number% EQU 6 goto h
pause >nul

:h
echo yes
pause >nul
exit

:n
echo no
pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: Honestly, if you just move the `:n` section above the `:h` you'll get (what I think is) your desired result.

Comment: How could there be an occasion where `%number% NEq 6`?

Comment: is that not something that can happen?

Comment: nvm i just fiured it out!

Comment: for anyone who needs the answer what i found out was it wont read the LSS and no matter what you enter it will go to h. so what i found out was that you can just `if %number%==6 goto h and then if it dosent detect that number it will skip that line and just goto n!
`@ECHO OFF
set /p number=
if %number%==6 goto h
goto n
pause >nul
:n
echo no
pause >nul
exit
:h
echo yes
pause >nul
exit

`

Comment: What `LSS`? You used `NEQ` and `EQU`, but not `LSS`.

Comment: ops i got confused with that. but i found a even better way. `@ECHO OFF
set /p number=
if %number%==y goto h
echo no 
pause >nul
exit 
:h
echo yes
pause >nul
exit

`
i didint even need n

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if %number% == 6 (
goto h
) else ( 
goto n
)
```

the reason your code did not work is because there are no EQL or NEQ operators in batch, and also your plan to just let the batch file go to the method automatically is not a good solution

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.